# Convergence of $\sum (\log k)^{- \log k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I can fairly easily work out that $\sum (\log k)^{-k}$ does converge using the ratio test, and I think I could use that somehow to work out whether $\sum (\log k)^{- \log k}$ converges. The ratio test and the root test don't give any result on this series, so I think there might be a clever comparison test I could do, but I don't see it.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471061/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-3-infty-frac1-log-log-n-log-n) is a stronger result.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that when I was searching, probably because I was searching for "log" instead of "ln".